# ListView OnClick Specific Item Not Working properly

Tags: android, listview

listview onclick item not return correct string it return package name
Example android.androidhive.materialdesign.detail@ahdyvh

Comment: add some code where you have tried something

Comment: sir i use custom adapter list view display all the data but when i click on that item it return android.androidhive.materialdesign.detail@ahdyvh this type of string

Comment: please show us itemclicklistener event and your adapter's getview method..

Comment: Have you added listeners for the item??

Comment: yes i am using listview.setonclickitemlister()

Comment: This question will be extremely difficult to answer without seeing your implementation.  Please update the question with the source code.

Comment: thanks all of you i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to handle the click event in the ListView

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   Mposition = position;
   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubDetalle.class));
}
```